# Python: making list of slices

Tags: python, range, slice

How can I make this code better:

```
slices = [slice(0,10), slice(10,20), slice(20,30), slice(30,40), slice(40,50),
         slice(50,60), slice(60, 70), slice(70, 80), slice(80,90), slice(90,100)]

for s in slices:
   some_function(s)
```

Number is up to 800s and I do need to change slice range too.

Edit:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadpoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as exec:
   slices = [slice(0,10), slice(10,20), slice(20,30),......]

   for s in slices:
      r = exec.map(some_function, some_list[s]))
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: Better, as in more concise?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
start, end, slice_range = 0, 800, 10
for i in range(start, end, slice_range):
   some_function(slice(i, i+slice_range))
```

The list can be completely eliminated, and you can also modify the range, start & stop point with just a single change! You can read more about range function [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp).

Answer (score 0):

try to use List Comprehensions

```
start, end, step = 0, 100, 10
slices = [slice(i, i+step) for i in range(start, end, step)]
print(slices)
```